# Call second coroutine function without blocking the first function

Tags: kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I have coroutine function that return the result of a network call.

I want my function to return the result and call another function in a parallel way without waiting for the second function to finish.

This is my function

```
suspend fun getResult() : NetworkResponse<ApiResult, ApiError>?
{
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        
        val localData : LocalData? = _localDataSource?.await()
        
        val result : NetworkResponse<ApiResult, ApiError>? = fetchFromNetwork(_localDataSource, localData).getOrNull()
        
        doAdditionalWork(localData, result)
        
        result
    }
}
```

And this is my second function

```
private suspend fun doAdditionalWork(localData : LocalData?, apiResponse : NetworkResponse<ApiResult, ApiError>?)
{
    delay(5000)
    //...
}
```

I just want the function 1 to return the result without waiting for the function 2. So how can i do it?

Comment: Why not just run `doAdditionalWork` after `getResult()` returns?

Comment: Because it's a function that run with every api call, so i need to put it in a centralized place instead of calling it manually after every api call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap it in `launch` or `async` block:

```
launch { doAdditionalWork(localData, result) }
```

It will run the function in parallel.

---

Other suggestion is to run `doAdditionalWork` after `getResult()` is executed:

```
someScope.launch {
    val resultPair = getResult()
    launch { doAdditionalWork(resultPair.second, resultPair.first) } // if you want to run it in parallel with the below code if any. 

    // if there are no other code to run in parallel, you can just call `doAdditionalWork(...)` without `launch` block

    // ... some other code if any
}

suspend fun getResult() : Pair<NetworkResponse<ApiResult, ApiError>, LocalData?>
{
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        
        val localData : LocalData? = _localDataSource?.await()
        
        val result : NetworkResponse<ApiResult, ApiError>? = fetchFromNetwork(_localDataSource, localData).getOrNull()
                    
        Pair(result, localData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but when in log, the result and the second function, they are printed in the same time. the expected behavior is printing the result of the function 1, and then printing the second function after 5 seconds

Comment: @GhailenSaada please see my updated answer.